# Issue dynamically creating inputs with angular attributes in an ng-repeat loop?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-show

I'm trying to create a directive which takes some JSON data, and creates a form. Each of the inputs in the form are contained in a `<div>` wrapper. The wrapper also contains a `<div>` that appears when `ng-show` is used. The `<div>` using `ng-show` is for dynamically displaying errors.

HTML for the Directive:

```
 <div class="input-wrapper" ng-repeat="inputData in contactCtrl.formInputData">
        <input type="text" class="text-input" placeholder="{{ inputData.placeholder }}" ng-model="inputData.model" />
        <div class="error-bubble" ng-show="inputData.showFunction">
        </div>
    </div>
```

HTML on the Page:

```
<div id="column-right">
            <h2>
                Send me an Email
            </h2>
            <contact-form></contact-form>
        </div>
```

Directive Creation:

```
spaModule.directive("contactForm", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "partials/directives/contact-form.html"
    }
});
```

JSON Data and a Validation Function:

```
this.formInputData = [
    {
        placeholder: "Name",
        model: "contactCtrl.clientName",
        showFunction: "!contactCtrl.validateName()"
    },
    {
        placeholder: "Email",
        model: "contactCtrl.email",
        showFunction: "!contactCtrl.validateEmail()"
    },
    {
        placeholder: "Subject",
        model: "contactCtrl.subject",
        showFunction: "!contactCtrl.validateSubject()"
    }
];
this.validateName = function() {
    if (this.clientName !== "") {
        this.nameError = "Name is required!";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Not a single piece of this is working. The placeholder is not being rendered correctly, `ng-show` is not doing anything, and the `ng-model` is not working. I've tried reformatting this as normal HTML in my page and everything works flawlessly.

The issue appears to be declaring `ng` attributes with `ng-repeat`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is the scope variable set?

Comment: I'm not using scope. I'm just using controlled as, and this. The page I'm linking is a route. The controller as is declared by route, not on the page.

Comment: it works more than you realize. The placeholder works fine. Problem is you are passing string values that need to be evaluated. See this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/LZw2ZdBAJqE4d084oDoY?p=preview Some fields are displaying properly. You need child directives to make this all work proplery though

Comment: The difference I saw was adding `this` to the `model` definition in the object. This will work?